# Is there a way to get merge.xts to leave names unchanged?

Tags: r, xts

Very little of what I use R for is performance sensitive, but for one slow task I have switched from using data frames to `xts` objects with a very gratifying speed-up of roughly 10x.

However, I have run into a quirk of `merge.xts`, which is that it seems to insist on checking column names when merging `xts` objects. The docs point out that the function extends `merge.zoo` and `merge.zoo` does obey `check.names = FALSE` but going by the code below `merge.xts` does not.

**Q: Is it possible to force `merge.xts` to leave my column names unchanged? And not, can I use `merge.zoo` (which does work) interchangeably on simple `xts` objects?**

```
library(xts)
set.seed(54321)
xts1 <- xts(runif(5, 100, 200), order.by = seq(as.Date('2013-01-14'),
                                as.Date('2013-01-18'), by = "day"))
xts2 <- xts(runif(5, 1000, 2000), order.by = seq(as.Date('2013-01-14'),
                                  as.Date('2013-01-18'), by = "day"))
names(xts1) <- 'my value 1'
names(xts2) <- 'my value 2'
xts1
xts2
xts.new <- merge.xts(xts1, xts2)
xts.new # names have been changed: unwanted behaviour
xts.new <- merge.xts(xts1, xts2, check.names = FALSE)
xts.new # argument is ignored, instead column called 'check.names' is added
zoo.new <- merge.zoo(xts1, xts2, check.names = FALSE)
zoo.new # check.names argument is honoured, names remain unchanged (good!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it not possible to force `merge.xts` to leave column names unchanged (without a patch to the underlying C code).

In your question, you used `merge.zoo` on your xts objects... so I'm not sure what your question is.  If you don't like that `zoo.new` is a zoo object, just wrap it in `as.xts`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. On the face of it the zoo objects look fine, I was just wondering if there were any hidden gotchas. I'll wrap 'em.